# Very large XML file generation

Tags: c#, xml

I have a requirement to generate an XML file. This is easy-peasy in C#. The problem (aside from slow database query [separate problem]) is that the output file reaches 2GB easily. On top of that, the output XML is not in a format that can easily be done in SQL. Each parent element aggregates elements in its children *and* maintains a sequential unique identifier that spans the file.
Example:

```
<level1Element>
    <recordIdentifier>1</recordIdentifier>
    <aggregateOfLevel2Children>11</aggregateOfL2Children>
    <level2Children>
        <level2Element>
        <recordIdentifier>2</recordIdentifier>
            <aggregateOfLevel3Children>92929</aggregateOfLevel3Children>
            <level3Children>
                <level3Element>
                    <recordIdentifier>3</recordIdentifier>
                    <level3Data>a</level3Data>
                </level3Element>
                <level3Element>
                    <recordIdentifier>4</recordIdentifier>
                    <level3Data>b</level3Data>
                </level3Element>
            </level3Children>
        </level2Element>
        <level2Element>
        <recordIdentifier>5</recordIdentifier>
            <aggregateOfLevel3Children>92929</aggregateOfLevel3Children>
            <level3Children>
                <level3Element>
                    <recordIdentifier>6</recordIdentifier>
                    <level3Data>h</level3Data>
                </level3Element>
                <level3Element>
                    <recordIdentifier>7</recordIdentifier>
                    <level3Data>e</level3Data>
                </level3Element>
            </level3Children>
        </level2Element>
    </level2Children>
</level1Element>
```

The schema in use actually goes up five levels. For the sake of brevity, I'm including only 3. I do not control this schema, nor can I request changes to it.

It's a simple, even trivial matter to aggregate all of this data in objects and serialize out to XML based on this schema. But when dealing with such large amounts of data, out of memory exceptions occur while using this strategy.

The strategy that is working for me is this: I'm populating a collection of entities through an ObjectContext that hits a view in a SQL Server database (a most ineffectively indexed database at that). I'm grouping this collection then iterating through, then grouping the next level then iterating through that until I get to the highest level element. I then organize the data into objects that reflect the schema (effectively just mapping) and setting the sequential `recordIdentifier` (I've considered doing this in SQL, but the amount of nested joins or CTEs would be ridiculous considering that the identifier spans the header elements into the child elements). I write a higher level element (say the `level2Element`) with its children to the output file. Once I'm done writing at this level, I move to the parent group and insert the header with the aggregated data and its identifier.

Does anyone have any thoughts concerning a better way output such a large XML file?

Comment: You want to know how to *output* it?  If you're using an [`XMLTextWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) on a reasonably modern machine, the file size should only be limited by the amount of hard disk space available.

Comment: Please show what you've tried.  There are many different ways to write XML output to a file.

Comment: May [the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432916/best-approach-to-write-huge-sql-dataset-into-xml-file/16433436#16433436) can help you.

Comment: How you are taking data out from the database into xml?Are u using Raw xml auto and ExecuteXmlReader?
Bit of detail is required about your implementation

Comment: An `XMLTextWriter` will probably work if I aggregate in the SQL query. The writer would allow me to increment the identifier while iterating through the entities without loading them all in memory. Due to the poorly indexed database, that's not an option for me. Feel free to post the `XMLTextWriter` as the answer.

Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, your problem is not with the limited space of storage i.e `HDD`. You have difficulty to maintain a large `XDocument` object in memory i.e `RAM`. To deal with this you can ignore make such a huge object. For each `recovrdIdentifier`  element you can call `.ToString()` and get a string. Now, simply append this strings to a file. Put declaration and root tag in this file and you're done.